# Cannot remove / hide Div Class with css

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, css-selectors, embedding

might be simple for some, I did went thru the CSS selectors guide... but can't select my item for it to disappear. I tried a lot of things since an hour but I'm knocking my head.

Website is RadioQuebec.tv, I embedded in an i-frame a gettr feed and i want to remove everything that is above the beginning of the posts section.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtJhU.jpg

Thanks, Tommy

Comment: Do you have some code? Are you trying to remove content with CSS? Can you edit the HTML?

Comment: I don't have any code, it's an Iframe i want to remove some stuff from it. Have a look at RadioQuebec.tv you'll see, i want the gettr feed to start at the first post.

Comment: Do you mean you want it like this? https://imgur.com/LP89U0R

Comment: Your css can't access what is inside the iframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use css like this:

```
body .jss55 .backTitle {
    display: none !important;
}
```